# What is wrong with this PHP 7 query script?

Tags: php, mysql

This is for PHP 7 to contact mysql.

I want to query the database called "database1" and for it to print the content of this db in the web browser.

```
<?php

function check_password($username, $password) {
// Create connection
$db = new mysqli('localhost','<DB-USERNAME>','<USER-PASSWORD>','<DATABASENAME>');

// Check for errors
if($db->connect_errno){
echo $db->connect_error;

}

$query = 'SELECT * FROM `<TABLENAME>`';

$result = mysqli_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    $message = 'Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error() - "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole Query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['firstname'];
    echo $row['lastname'];

}

mysqli_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: you have error  ??  ..

Comment: First of all, your connection function isn't correct- Google how to connect to a MySQL database. Also, you've mixing up`mysql` and `mysqli` - you always want to use the `mysqli_*` functions (or `PDO_*`) since `mysql_*` is deprecated and not longer supported in PHP7.

Comment: Also you're trying to select rows from "database1" ?? you have to provide a Table name (e.g. "users", "workers", "invoices") instead of Database name. In `mysqli` connection you have already this Database in use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php)

Comment: I also used an example table including example php code an got: Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user '<user>'@'localhost' to database '<name>'. All privileges has been granted to <user> though.

Answer (score 3):

Initially, you start using the MYSQLI extension, which is an improved version of old MYSQL extension.

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost','DB-USERNAME','<USER-PASSWORD>','<DATABASE');
```

And then suddenly you start using old MYSQL extension and that is the error.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

**Be consistent, use only one type of extension. Don't mix.**

I recommended you to use the new and improved MYSQLI extension

[Visit the PHP documentation site for more information about the MYSQLI extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

And also the old MYSQL extension is deprecated in PHP version 5.5.0 and removed in PHP version 7.0.0. [Click here for more information](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)